# Weird glitch after switching to the viewport *Rendered*

Tags: rendering

Suddenly after working on blender I had to with to the shading tap and the lighting on the scene started to glitch.

[image]

Comment: Most likely an issue with the GPU (AMD?) Update the drivers.

Comment: I am gonna check that, thank you

Comment: This happens to me too. First, everything turns GREEN and a while later it glitches! Been looking for answer but this doesn't sound common.
Have you found the solution to this?
I'm working on an imac Pro with Radeon Pro Vega 56 8 Go. Thanks

Comment: Issues with GPU drivers... macOS and blender not very good friends currently.